# Custom maven plugin: saving pom NOT effective pom

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I wrote code for maven plugin that updates version number in a pom file. However when I try to save new pom, it is being saved as Effective pom. Is there a way to save it the way it was before parsing?
Thank you!

```
private MavenProject project;
String newVersion = updateProjectVersion(project);
project.setVersion(newVersion);

// write project object into pom file
MavenXpp3Writer pomWriter = new MavenXpp3Writer();
releasePomFile = ReleaseUtil.getStandardPom(project);
Writer fileWriter = null;
String scmUrl = project.getScm().getConnection();
fileWriter = WriterFactory.newXmlWriter(releasePomFile);
pomWriter.write(fileWriter, project.getModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/), which was especially written for these kind of tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did use build-helper:parse-version release:update-versions to achieve the same goal. However since I need to update only "minor" section of the version in a pom and I cannot hardcode new version numbers, using existing plugins turned out to be a batch script. And the requirement is to use custom maven plugin. I have source code for maven release plugin, which does update "revision" and "qualififer" parts of version in a pom without expanding pom file. I just cannot figure out how it does it..

Comment: I guess my other choice (if it's possible) is to call UpdateVersionsMojo of the release plugin from within my plugin and somehow pass developmentVersion parameter to it.